# Create gallery with elements floating side by side or table cells

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Friends I'm new to Android and I'm facing all those beginner's problems such as overload of information in the first steps of the learning proccess.

I want to develop an activity where its content resembles a picture gallery, with 2 pics per row. With HTML + CSS I would create divs with float:left and half of the parent element's width. Or maybe creating a table with two cells per row. Wouldnt do that in HTML for a photo gallery but I know it works.

I want to do this programmatically and Ive seen solutions with TableLayout and RelativeLayout. But i dont understand how to create a container such as DIV in HTML for the data (will be a title and an image) i want to place in the layout. And i dont understand how to make every two of them side by side.

How would you do that in terms of layout and programming?

I will update this thread with an image to a better understanding of my problem later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below `XML` code as template to inflate in your activity and then add to `ListView`

1. In Main Activity inflate view by `LayoutInflater`:

   ```
   LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity() .getLayoutInflater();
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_stats_layout, null);
   ```
2. Use Above view as item in ListView - Use this tutorial for custom `ListView`
     http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/img1" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/img2" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Img1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Img2"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So you re telling me that correct elements to use as containers of other elements are RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc?

Comment: Yes, but you can use TableLayout & FrameLayout too. Imagine a situation where you have 5000 images & you are manually creating Layout. Using Above approach you can use TableLayout & FrameLayout & then create XML file with single table & then inflate it inside Activity.